# Position dodge on a flipped axis with error bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating depth plots in ggplot2 using the following data frame:

```
TTTTOM<- data.frame(Treatment=c("Mineral", "Mineral", "Mineral", "OM", "OM", "OM", "Veg", "Veg", "Veg"), Depth2=c(-7.5, -4.5, -1.5, -7.5, -4.5, -1.5, -7.5, -4.5, -1.5), mean=c(2.83, 3.33, 3.16, 9.16, 11.17, 11.67, 4.83, 5, 5.17), se=c(0.7, 1.12, 0.65, 2.41, 3.28, 3.12, 1.83, 1.71, 0.95))
```

I've used this code with ggplot2 to create a plot, but the position dodge doesn't seem to be working with the error bars the same way it is working for the lines and points. I need my error bars to run through my points (i.e. have them dodged by the same amount). Thanks for your help.

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.3) 
ggplot(TTTTOM, aes(x=Depth2, y=mean, linetype=Treatment)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Treatment), colour="black", size=0.75, position=pd) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), linetype=1, colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +
  geom_point(colour="black",shape=16, size=2.0, position=pd) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1, 2, 4), labels=c("Organic", "Mineral", "Vegetated"))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0), linetype="dashed")+
  theme(legend.position="none",
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=18, margin=margin(10,0,0,0)),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.text=element_text(size=18),
    legend.key.width=unit(2,"line"),
    axis.text=element_text(size=18),
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=16, margin=margin(0,10,0,0)),
    plot.margin = unit(c(.25, .25, .25, .25), "in"))+
  labs(x=paste("Distance from \n sediment surface (cm)"), y="% Total OM") +
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,0))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to geom_errorbar() needs a group argument; in this case, **group=Treatment**:

```
pd <- position_dodge(.3) 

ggplot(TTTTOM, aes(x=Depth2, y=mean, linetype=Treatment)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Treatment), colour="black", size=0.75, position=pd) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se, group=Treatment), 
            linetype=1, colour="black", width=.1, position=pd) +
  geom_point(colour="black",shape=16, size=2.0, position=pd) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1, 2, 4), labels=c("Organic", "Mineral", "Vegetated"))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0), linetype="dashed")+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=18, margin=margin(10,0,0,0)),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=18),
        legend.key.width=unit(2,"line"),
        axis.text=element_text(size=18),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=16, margin=margin(0,10,0,0)),
        plot.margin = unit(c(.25, .25, .25, .25), "in"))+
  labs(x=paste("Distance from \n sediment surface (cm)"), y="% Total OM") +
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,0))+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]